# Can you still make opportunity attacks while prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, prone

Im playing a ranger in DnD 4e and I just wanted to know if you can still make opportunity attacks while prone?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** Being prone does not prevent you from attacking or even moving (you can still use the *Crawl* move action), so you can still make opportunity attacks, presuming the target is range.